# Extreme value at a point that does not exist.

Tags: calculus

If we have a function $f(x)=x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ you would agree that the absolute minimum would be $f(0)=0$

But what if $f(x)=x$ is defined only on the open interval $(0,1)$ ?
The absolute minimum cannot be at $x=0$ as it is not defined there.

Similarly what is the absolute minimum of $f(x)=x^3/x$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ ?
Again the absolute minimum cannot be at $x=0$ as it is not defined there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that says that a continuous function takes on both maximum and minimum values on a **closed and bounded** set.  You give an example of a continuous function on a set that is **not** closed so does not fit that theorem.  There is no minimum value.

[-1, 1] is both closed and bounded but the function is not continuous so that theorem does not apply.

Comment: So even if the value "just next to the value that does not exist" (that does not have a specific value as we are working with real numbers) has the lowest value, the absolute minimum does not exist entirely?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the maximum or a minimum of a function may not happen. One can get that a continuous function achieves its maximum and minimum on a compact set, which may fail when on a non-compact set.

For the general case, like the example you gave, you could just discuss the supremum and the infimum of the function on the interval.